# How do I get answers after editing a question?

Tags: support, questions, answers, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

I asked a java question here: [How can I make this method end its recursion and reach a maximum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560151/ap-comp-sci-homework-in-java)

But because I left out the last part of it - the actual code that had a problem - I got no actual answers. Then, once I edited it so it contained all needed info, I got no responses because it wasn't new anymore, and people saw that it had a few comments and one answer.

So my question is, once I've fudged up a question, how do I get it answered?

Comment: Please note that an edit actually bumps the question.

Comment: I've edited your question to be less focused on the homework and made it slightly shorter by removing obsolete text and/or newlines, that way it addresses your problem a bit better while being a bit shorter in length. If you see a way to make it even shorter without removing details, feel free to apply it. It might however be the case that people think the same as the current answer, which means that your problem might be NP-complete and can't be solved. However, as it is provided by a book and a teacher, it shouldn't.

Comment: **Related blog post:** [How to get your questions answered?](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do that! Hopefully I get an answer or can crack what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You can [start a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)